# Symbolic link to persistent storage dissappears

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

On Openshift v3 (free) I manually created a symbolic link in my app working directory (opt/app-root/src) to a mounted persistent storage in /data. After I have to rebuild or if Openshift decides to restart, this link is deleted. How do I make this symbolic link persistent? On Openshift v2 I used to solve this problem using Action Hooks, which no longer exists on OSv3.
Thanks

Comment: If you are symlinking to the ``/data`` directory, and not just a file in it, why don't you just mount the volume at the location where you are creating the symlink? Or are you adding symlinks from multiple places, or to individual files?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. It might solve your problem.

https://github.com/getwarped/action-hooks

Comment: I'll check. Thanks.